# What is the hash algorithm for owncloud passwords

Tags: hashing, owncloud, algorithm

I need to know the algorithm used to generate the password hashs that look like this: `$2a$08$ztQUBr1vx97Rc9MiJVr05.LZWg92jGYkRFEJViHhfZjaWpB0xfgGu`

It looks like bcrypt to me but when I hashed my password using a script they did not match up. So I believe something else is done to the password before storing it inside a database. Is it a salt? If so, what is it?

Comment: Have you looked into the source code? Or the configuration? https://github.com/owncloud/core/blob/80b15b48c594a36a2620a48ab92eac9c208073a9/config/config.sample.php#L51 Seems a salt is involved, somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[crypt(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html#NOTES) states that the `$2a$` prefix indicates Blowfish. The OpenBSD [crypt(3)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man3/bcrypt.3?query=crypt&sec=3) provides some further details on the format.

If you have a glibc with Blowfish support, you can basically just call `crypt()` yourself, or use another program that does this. I've found [makepasswd](https://github.com/khorben/makepasswd) to be useful for this purpose.

To see details of the algorithm, you probably want to refer to actual source code. PHP has a version of [crypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) with [built-in Blowfish support](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/crypt_blowfish.c), which can be easily called from its interactive mode (`php -a`). If that doesn't work out, you probably want to dig into the ownCloud source.